# classification of rank $2$ $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-algebra with invertible discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ be an integer. Let $A$ be an $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-algebra of rank $2$ whose discriminant is non invertible. In Serre's book lecture on the mordell Weil theorem (in the appendix at the end) he says that $A$ is completely determined by whether $A/pA \cong \mathbb{F}_p^2$ or $A/pA \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. The reason there are only those two possibilities for $A/pA$ is that $A/pA$ is a two dimensional reduced algebra over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and as such is a product of finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

So my question is how do you prove serre's remark.

Comment: $A$ is finite-dimensional? Otherwise I don't know what you mean by discriminant.

Comment: OK they were some serious flaws in my question, I edited it. Very sorry

Comment: I think this questions fits perfectly to mathoverflow.

Comment: Ok I did, thanks for the suggestion.